# glht() giving same std. error for each treatment

Tags: r, lme4, multcompview

I'm trying to do a Dunnett's test on a linear mixed model using lme4 and glht.
I set up and ran the model as below

```
Untransformed.lmer <- lmer(Sum ~ Treatment + (1|Block), data = EggCounts_poolSUM)
anova(Untransformed.lmer)
summary(glht(Untransformed.lmer, linfct = mcp(Treatment = 'Dunnett'), alternative = 'less'))
```

And when I run that I get the following output

```
     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts


Fit: lmer(formula = Sum ~ Treatment + (1 | Block), data = EggCounts_poolSUM)

Linear Hypotheses:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(<z)  
75 - 0 >= 0    -914.2      911.6  -1.003  0.372  
150 - 0 >= 0  -1207.4      911.6  -1.325  0.243  
300 - 0 >= 0  -2162.2      911.6  -2.372  0.030 *
600 - 0 >= 0  -1446.3      911.6  -1.587  0.160  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Can someone explain how all treatments could end up with the same Std. error? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to share your data, most likely there's something weird about your predictors. you can also check the variance covarience with vcov(Untransformed.lmer)

Answer (score 0):

The Dunnett standard error for treatment `i` is `sqrt(s2) * sqrt(1/ni + 1/n0)` where `s2` is the pooled variance estimate, `ni` is the number of observations for treatment `i` and `n0` is the number of observations for the reference group. So the standard errors are all the same in the case when the `ni`'s are equal. This is likely the case for your data.